# Flutter:: New is not expanding when right click on lib

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter,

When I try to add a new dart File in lib, I right-click on lib and hover the mouse pointer on New, it is not expanding further

[image]

I run command **flutter doctor**, everything is fine also i run **flutter upgrade** but not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on new then vs code open a text field in file area, and you can enter filename with extension like

> example.dart

And hit enter button from key board

Comment: yes I am doing exactly like this, but I want the way i mentioned above